# How can you make a UITabBarController go directly to your address book?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tabbarcontroller

I saw an implementation, but I need help as to where it exactly goes. So I've got the TabBarController open and I saw code such as this to put in

```
picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
// place the delegate of the picker to the control
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
picker.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:picker.view];
```

This was the original question
"I would like to display a `UIAddressBook` inside my `UITabBarController` (*which is also embedded in a UINavigationController*) instead of displaying it modally every single time. In other words, I would like to access an address-book inside an already-existing tab bar controller and navigation controller. When I display it modally, the two disappear since it's an entirely new view. However, I could not find the documentation to embed it. Does anyone have any pointers?"

So to clarify where I stand, I've got a new TabBar project setup and I want the 2nd tab bar to open up contacts automatically. How do I go about doing that? Sorry for my ignorance, I'm very new to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is Simple example of that use for you/beginners.**

Following code help you for get most of data of people from contact list.

First Add all Delegate and Datasource method in your class **.h file**

```
<ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate,ABPersonViewControllerDelegate,ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate,ABUnknownPersonViewControllerDelegate>
```

Create `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
        [[picker navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
        // Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
        NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],nil];


        picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
        // Show the picker
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
```

Add Following Delegate and DataSource method of `ABPeopelPickerNavigationController`

```
#pragma mark - ABPeopelPickerNavigationController Delegate and DataSource Methods

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *)unknownCardViewController didResolveToPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
}

- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
}

- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier;
{
    return YES;
}
```

Below code for get all the information of people from phonebook

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    int i;
    NSString *strName = @"";
    NSString* company = @"";
    NSString *address = @"";
    NSString *suburb = @"";
    NSString *postalcode = @"";
    NSString *state = @"";
    NSString *country = @"";
    NSString *mobile = @"";
    NSString *phone = @"";
    NSString *emailid = @"";


    strName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName((ABRecordRef) person);
    CFStringRef name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName((ABRecordRef) person);
    company  = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef) person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);

    NSArray*  allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook,name);
    CFRelease(name);

    for (i = 0; i < [allPeople count]; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef record = [allPeople objectAtIndex:i];

        ABMutableMultiValueRef multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonAddressProperty);
        for(CFIndex i=0; i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiValue); i++)
        {
            NSString* HomeLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiValue, i);
            if([HomeLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
            {
                CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, i);
                address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey)];
                suburb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCityKey)];
                postalcode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressZIPKey)];
                state = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStateKey)];
                country = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCountryKey)];

                CFRelease(dict);
            }
            CFRelease(HomeLabel);
        }
        CFRelease(multiValue);
    }
    CFRelease(allPeople);


    ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSString* mobileLabel = nil;
    for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++)
    {
        mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
        if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
        {
            mobile = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
            NSLog(@"phone   %@",mobile);
        }
        else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
        {
            phone = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i);
            NSLog(@"phone   %@",phone);

            CFRelease(mobileLabel);
            break ;
        }
        CFRelease(mobileLabel);

    }
    CFStringRef value, label;
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    CFIndex count = ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);
    if (count == 1)
    {
        value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
        emailid = (NSString*) value;
        NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
        CFRelease(value);
    }
    else
    {
        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);
            value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);

            // check for Work e-mail label
            if (CFStringCompare(label, kABWorkLabel, 0) == 0)
            {
                emailid = (NSString*) value;
                NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
            }
            else if(CFStringCompare(label, kABHomeLabel, 0) == 0)
            {
                emailid = (NSString*) value;
                NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
            }

            CFRelease(label);
            CFRelease(value);
        }
    }
    CFRelease(multi);

        }


    CFRelease(phones);
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;

}
```

For more information read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html) and [this](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2009/01/21/cocoa-touch-tutorial-extract-address-book-address-values-on-iphone-os/) tutorial.

**Thanks :)**

Comment: iPatel, Thanks for that. I've seen both and as far as the Apple code, I've done the address book and the quick contacts. My issue is more so how do I tie that "IBAction" is those examples to a tabBar icon?